# When a star loses temperature its matter loses KE so does it mean the star's gravity weaken?

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, astrophysics, stellar-evolution

When a star loses temperature its matter loses KE so does it mean the star's gravity weaken? The question is based on Einstein's field equation which states that energy also contributes in space-time curvature or gravity. Is the ratio of rest mass energy and kinetic energy that rules in the possible difference in curvature of spacetime when the star cools down?

A follow up question: only if my first question is right and if black holes don't lose temperature and if their temperature is low does it mean their gravity strength is stable?

Comment: A stars thermal energy is very low compared to its mass. That doesnt answer your question just saying it’s a small effect if it is included. C is big so c^2 huge delta-m=E/c^2

Comment: For a Sun-like star the ratio of thermal energy to total energy is around 1 part per million. So the thermal energy of our Sun is roughly equivalent to the mass of Mars, maybe a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Black holes theoretically radiate Hawking radiation and lose mass over time, s o their gravity strength decreases over time.

It's true that a star's total energy decreases when it loses KE, and mass-energy should contribute to gravitation. In the balance between pressure and gravity, it is losing a higher percentage of its pressure than of its gravity, so gravity is still winning over pressure in this scenario.

Comment: Black holes won't be losing mass for a very long time. They need to be warmer than the CMB to do that.